# How to automatically recover from Bluemix Secure Gateway EPIPE error?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

After running a bluemix secure gateway for a couple hours, I eventually start getting EPIPE errors.  The only way I've found to resolve these is to delete and recreate the Secure Gateway Service (and then reconfigure things which depended on the gateway).   Is there a way to automatically recover from EPIPE errors?  I've tried stopping and restarting the docker container, but the only thing that fixed was to actually delete the service.

Answer (score 0):

An EPIPE condition can no longer arise on our current level of server code. Please re-try your operation.